# migrating from rxjava1 to 2

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am currently using rxJava1 and want to migrate to rxjava2. Facing lots of issues migrating, especially with imports.

this is my sample code :-

```
private void loginCall(final Observable<ResponseLogin> login) {
      {
        try {
            login.
                    subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseLogin>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            mView.showToast("Something Went Wrong. 
Please try again.");
                            mView.signUpFailure(e.getMessage());

mView.loginAnalyticsResponse(e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(ResponseLogin response) {
                            try {
                                String jsonResponse = new Gson().toJson(response);
                                mView.loginAnalyticsResponse(jsonResponse);
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }

                            if (response != null) {
                                mModel.saveLoginDataInApp(response);
                                Log.d("AAAA",""+response.getData().getProfile().getStage());
                                mView.signUpSuccess(response);
                            } else {
                                mView.showToast("Result is Empty");
                                //mView.signUpFailure(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

These are the imports I am using:-

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Observer;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
```

Please help me move this code to rxjava2

Comment: https://medium.com/lifesum-healthy-living-simplified/how-we-migrated-from-rxjava1-to-rxjava2-bcf0c9eb1a6f

Comment: Please read [what's different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/docs/What's-different-in-2.0.md).